# I want to set a custom status for my discord bot (aka "Playing | $help for commands")

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm making my bot with the discord.py rewrite, and using the AutoShardedBot class system. I want to set a custom playing status, but every time I search for it the answers are for discord.Client(). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example setting a custom playing status when the bot starts up:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="| $help for commands"))
```

This isn't the *only* way to do it, but it's a method that I use because it allows you to easily change between `listening`, `watching`, etc.

---

And if you want to add the `on_ready()` event to a cog:

```py
def MyCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready():
        print("Ready!")
        await bot.change_presence(...)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.change_presence()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence)
- [`discord.ActivityType`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ActivityType)
- [`Cog.listener()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener) - Listeners for events in cogs.

Comment: See the edit for using the `on_ready` event in a cog ^

Answer (score 1):

```
//set your status
client.user.setActivity("Being a bot or something lol", {type: "Playing",})
```